# I can't understand the while loop here

Tags: python-3.x

```
def lcm(x,y):
  lcm=max(x,y)#assume x and y be 9 and 15 respectively then lcm is 15
  while lcm%x !=0 or lcm%y !=0:# loop should be end when 15 is divided by 9 but loop is not ending
    lcm+=1
return lcm
x=int(input('enter the number'))
y=int(input('enter the number'))
print(lcm(x,y))
```

While loop should end when remainder is not `0` but it is not ending it just continues and when remainder is `0` it ends. Just like value of `x` and `y` is 9 and 15. `lcm` is greater value among `x` and `y` then `lcm` is 15. When `lcm(15)` is divided by 9 its remainder is not 0. The loop should be end at this time because remainder is not 0 and I have used (or) it means at least one statements needs to be not 0 to terminate loop. But loop continue till 45 how?

Comment: You have used `or` which means either of the both condition can be true.

Comment: In order for the loop to stop, both conditions need to be `False`. Maybe easier to understand if you convert to the equivalent: `while not(lcm % x == 0 and lcm % y == 0):`

Answer (score 0):

For a while loop to end, its condition must be false. It runs **while** the condition is true. Your while loop's condition is `lcm%x !=0 or lcm%y !=0`, which `lcm%x !=0` is false and `lcm%y !=0` is false. That is, it will run until lcm is divisible by both `x` and `y`.